# Apache Bench POST: Is it possible to read from string or stdin, instead of a file?

Tags: apache, http, apachebench

I have an Apache Bench POST test command like:

`ab -p test.json -n 1000 -c 100 -T "application/json" "http://localhost:8080/test"`

However, my test.json is very simple, e.g.:

`{"foo": 1}`

Is it possible to read that in directly to the `ab` command, without a file reference? Something like:

`ab -p '{"foo": 1}' -n 1000 -c 100 -T "application/json" "http://localhost:8080/test"`

*(I know that doesn't work, just wondering if there is a good linux file mimic trick or something)*

My only workaround currently is:

`echo '{"foo": 1}' > test.json && ab -p test.json -n 1000 -c 100 -T "application/json" "http://localhost:8080/test" && rm test.json`

But I find that a bit too clunky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
cat test.json | ab -p /dev/stdin -n 1000 -c 100 -T "application/json" "http://localhost:8080/test"
```